# Search a range for highlighted cells that are not empty

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to search through a range of cells B2:W6 to find highlighted cells that are not empty and return the values in those cells. I currently have no code or idea how to start this.

Not all cells are highlighted but if there is a cell that is highlighted and isn't empty i'd like to return that value in a msgbox.

The highlighted color is the generic yellow highlight, it's default.

Something along the lines of:

```
With Range("B2:W6")

If Cell is highlighted and <> "" Then

MsgBox Cell.Value

End If
End With
```

Comment: I do not have any code I do not know how to do it.

Comment: I just don't know how to check if a cell is highlighted

Comment: Try checking the InteriorColor property - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.color

Comment: and when you are checking for an empty string, you have to include the cell reference there too, you cant just put `and <>` - and your cell reference needs to be qualified.

Comment: that link has very little information and I do not think it is what I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check each cell you will have to use a For loop, for which you also need to declare a variable "element".

Then, for each cell in the given range, you want to make sure it's not empty and want to make sure the cell's interior color is yellow.

The following code should do the trick:

```
Sub Name()
Dim element as Variant

For Each element in Range("B2:W6")

    If element.Value <> "" and element.Interior.Color = RGB(255,255,0) Then

        MsgBox element.Value 'Use this if you want a pop up window for each match
        Debug.Print(element.Value) 'Use this to print all results in the Immediate window in VBA (quicker)

    End If

Next element
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow And cell.Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox ("Notify " & cell.Value & " that his time has changed")
    End If
Next cell
```